# wpf dynamically adding new textblocks to grid - scroll problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add new textblocks to new grid, which has 3 rows, by clicking button. After 3 new textblocks I want that fourth textblock will be "under" screen and user will has to scroll down. But in my code textblock doesn't want to be in 4 row, it just display again in 3rd row.

Here's my code:

xaml:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add new textblock" Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0" Width="130px" Height="70" 
                    Click="btnAdd_Click"/>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="newGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                              CanContentScroll="True"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

I know that in xaml I declared 3 rows in Grid, but I want to create new rows dynamically and only 3 rows will be displayed in screen - next rows will be displayed after scrolling.

c#:

```
        int count = 0;

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            tb.Text = now.ToString();
            tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            tb.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            tb.FontSize = 20;
            tb.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0);
            tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;

            newGrid.Children.Add(tb);
            Grid.SetRow(tb, count); // when textblock is in 3rd row, 4rd cannot be created as I want
            Grid.SetColumn(tb, 0);
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test your problem, but i guess it is because you only have 3 Rows in your RowsDefinition.

Something like:

```
newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: That's not what I wanted, because it keeps adding new rows on the screen, and I wanted to add new rows "under" the screen in order to scroll down. In this solution if there is too much rows they started to overlap.

Comment: To make sure i Understand you correctly. You want to have a Grid, where 3 Pre defined Rows are displayed on the screen.

If you press the "Add new textblock" Button, another new Row sould be added below the 3 previous screen, in the same Grid, but they should be displayed below the screen?